# insert multiple text in every container on flutter

Tags: flutter

I have 2 container and I wanna insert some text in every container (text1 and text2 in my code), can someone help me to solve this case?

```
body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 30,
                  text1
                  text2
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 30,
                  text1
                  text2
                )
              ],
            )
```

Comment: You don't have 2 columns. you have 1 column

Comment: ohh sorry, i mean 2 container

Comment: What are `text1` and `text2`? are they `Text` widgets? or strings?

Comment: strings sir, it's just an example i want to make

Comment: It is not clear how do you like to show them, consider updating question including   your desire output and provide proper snippet that will produce the issue

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `Column` as the container's child :

```dart
body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 30,
                  child: Column(
                   children:[
                    text1
                    text2
                  ]
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 30,
                  child: Column(
                   children:[
                    text1
                    text2
                  ]
                )
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

To present string on UI you can use `Text` widget. If the is all about merging text you can do `"$text1 $text2` or `text1+text2`

```dart
body: Column(
children: <Widget>[
  Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 30,
      child: Text("$text1 $text2")),
  Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 30,
      child: Text(text1 + text2))
],
)
```

And if it is about column wise, insert another column for simplicity

```dart
body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 30,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(text1),
            Text(text2),
          ],
        )),
    Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 30,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(text1),
            Text(text2),
          ],
        ))
  ],
)
```

There are others way to represent and style text like using [`RichText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html).

More about [`Text`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/Text-class.html) and [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)